# Trace Netsuite Scripts Logic from file Cabinet

Tags: bundler, netsuite, suitescript

I have a scenario where I want to search the whole scripts stored in the file cabinet for a particular logic. Is there any good tool or bundle to accomplish the same?.

Answer (score 1):

I just use Eclipse and search the workspace, when I have a need like that.  For me, it is usually right after starting a new company, when I'm reviewing all of the existing scripting.  Just pull all scripts to Eclipse (I recommend doing that periodically, anyway, so you have a backup), then search the workspace.

Not the fastest way, I'm sure, but it has always worked for me. :)

Comment: I know the way but that's not very helpful. I am searching for some bundle kind of thing.

Comment: I've never heard of any bundles.  There was a company that had an audit bundle they sold, that would search for scripted dependencies, I don't remember the name though...

Answer (score 0):

I think @W3BUGY's way is more intuitive. IDE can help you efficiently. But if you want the search execute in NetSuite. You can use a Map Reduce Script to make it. Here are some sketchy steps. Hope it helps.

1. Search javascript file within your target folder. (GetInput)
2. Get each one's internal Id, load file, get contents and search the text in it. (Map)
3. Return the result by mails or save to custom record (Summarize)